# Why access denied happen with mysql , with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I'm trying to create mySQL container for development DB.
My app is made by golang.

Now, I created docker-compose.yml to run APP & DB.
mySQL container was created and I can start it, but Access denied shows up if when I tried to connect with this DB, via DB client (Sequel Pro).

it's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3' 
  services:   app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    volumes:   mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.10
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pass'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql volumes:   mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

I did

```
$ docker-compose build
```

and

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Then containers are created, mySQL is as below, if exec command
$ docker ps -a

```
1f7540fdedc1        mysql:5.7.10        "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   1 second ago             Up 2 seconds                0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   XXX_mysql_1
```

After that,If I tried to connect this DB with sequel pro, I can see this message in kitematic.

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

ip, user name, password, port must be correct.

Also, if I create docker container for mySQL with using kitematic, I can connect with the container.

I don't know why access denied shows up.

[Screenshot when access denied shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZIBX.png)

Comment: does it work if you run `docker exec -it mysql mysql -uroot -ppass` ?

Comment: @EliasPlatek If running this command, Enter password shows up, and input "pass" (Same password as that is set in docker-compose.yml).
Then , it returned   


  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: then your container is not correctly initialized. Try to clear the volume, remount your docker-compose instance and run `docker-compose logs -f mysql` to get additional informations on the possible errors

Comment: @EliasPlatek I did docker-compose down and rebuild, up and see log about sql. It shows some waring ,like
`
'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
`
But there are no error message.
Access denied still happen ...

Comment: Try this once. changing how you set your root password 
      `- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= "devpassword"` 
This has solve the issue many time for me

Answer (score 1):

I have this similar problem fixed. Make sure you have the latest image of mysql version. `docker pull mysql:5.7.10`.

Then delete the associated volume (backup if there is existing data). If you are using the docker-compose yml version 3 you should map your environment like `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password`. Verify that it is correctly set by going to the container and run command `echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

If you are logging in from the host machine try to pass the protocol flag.
`mysql -u root -p --protocol=tcp` (you may also pass the host localhost or 127.0.0.1) `-h 127.0.0.1`